# Must a specialist wizard variant choose prohibited schools?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wizard

If using the [Specialist wizard variant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/specialistWizardVariants.htm#Specialist%20Wizard%20Variant) from *Unearthed Arcana (page 59 in the book)*, does the wizard need to choose one or more prohibited school(s) of magic as they are already sacrificing their familiar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Quoting from the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/specialistWizardVariants.htm) (just because I don't have the book to hand):

> Each specialist class has three variants: one that replaces the specialist's summon familiar ability

The specialist gives up something *additional* in order to get the listed benefit (e.g. resistance to energy for an abjurer). They still have to select prohibited schools in order to get the "regular" benefits of being a specialist wizard (extra spells per day, etc). This applies even if the benefit chosen is that which gives up the extra spells per day - in that case, the wizard has essentially gained the benefit in exchange for taking on the prohibited schools.